# asp net core get user async fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a model that contains the id of the current user, every after create/edit the user it includes its id

Model code:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(2)]
    public string DocumentCode { get; set; }

    public string DocumentName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    //Id of the current logged user
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Controller code:

```
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,DocumentCode,DocumentName")] Document document)
    {
        if (id != document.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                document.UpdatedBy = _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User).Id.ToString();
                _context.Update(document);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!DocumentExists(document.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(document);
    }
```

Error after Edit more than twice.

> InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this
>   context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members
>   are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()
```

How can I possibly fix this issue? First click is ok, but second is not. The error both occurs in Create and Edit function.

Comment: Your `_userManager` is not the built-in `UserManager<TUser>` type, is it? Because your code should not compile at all. If it’s not the default, you should show the code of that type. Also, show the exact error message including the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call it with **await** keyword:

```
document.UpdatedBy = (await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User)).Id.ToString();
```

In simple words when you call an async method without **async** keyword your code doesn't wait for the asynchronous **GetUserAsync** method to finish. So it keeps running when you call the next method but your data is not ready yet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

Comment: It gives me error String does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter etc..

Comment: @aleha, I missed parenthesis there, not it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, that `GetUserAsync` returns `Task<User>` object, then it should be awaited first. Then access its properties.

```
document.UpdatedBy = await (_userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User)).Id.ToString();
```

Will be better to check for null here.

```
document.UpdatedBy = await (_userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User))?.Id.ToString() ?? string.empty;
```

Comment: If it is not a problem for you, can you explain the case in deep if you can?

Comment: It gives me error String does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter etc..

Comment: await GetUserAsync first. Or update your question with GetUserAsync  code